# Movie with giant alien fish creature?

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find the name of a sci-fi movie I saw as a kid. I remember only bits and my memory may be off.

I believe it took place on an alien space ship or saucer submerged at the bottom of a lake or ocean. I remember that there was a circular room on the ship (hence my thought that it was a saucer) that had hatches in the wall. Each hatch apparently contained an egg of some sort as in the movie, a door to one of the hatches opens and an egg is revealed. I sort of remember the egg on a conveyor belt somehow, but I'm not sure.

Anyway cut to sometime later and the egg has grown into some sort of fish creature.

I don't recall anything else about the plot. The movie was in color and, guessing, is from the 60s, give or take.

Comment: Did you actually see this in the 60's or 70's, making you believe it was from that time frame, or is that just your best guess?

Comment: I'm not quite certain this is a perfect match to your description but there is a film called 'Destination Inner Space' which can be read about on IMDb at http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060302/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1. There are various some clips on https://www.youtube.com.

This film features an alien spaceship under water with a circular chamber which has a series of triangular doors surrounding an opening into the ocean. There is also a "fish creature" which hatches from an egg.

Comment: I don't know the last time I saw this movie. Might have been as late as the 90s. It left a lasting impression but not an accurate one. The movie popped back into my head after watching Humanoids from the Deep last night.

Comment: Mr. Morgan, thank you! You've found the movie!!! That's it! Destination Inner Space. Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: @Jeff N: I've turned my comment earlier into an answer, if you can do the honours and accept it please. Oddly enough, I was looking for this very film myself recently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described above as a comment, the film is called 'Destination Inner Space' which can be read about on [IMDb](http://imdb.com/title/tt0060302/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). There are some clips on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com). The whole film can be found [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xls9rg_destination-inner-space_shortfilms) but the video is not of the best quality.

The film features an alien spaceship under water with a circular chamber which has a series of triangular doors surrounding an opening into the ocean. There is also a "fish creature" which hatches from an egg.